# Converting Hourly Data to Daily Data for many different Excel files

Tags: excel, matlab, time-series, aggregate

I have been downloading and organizing hourly water quality data into Excel for many different states, and have organized them by year. I have done data prep for them to make sure there are no zeros/every day of the year (DOY) has 24 values, but the time series plots were too noisy so want me to get the daily average values instead.

All of the sites annual data is different in terms of how many days are available, and sometimes they are missing whole months due to no recordings.

So my question is, how can I develop a code to give me the average daily value linked to a specific DOY that I can apply to many different Excel sheets. The data appears like this:

[image]

And the files are saved like like CA1_2012 (California Site 1 hourly data from 2012)

I know there is a lot on this topic but I have been trying everything and I can't get a code that works!

Comment: Can you at least post what you tried?

Comment: PIvotTable in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the summation of the second column based on values in the first column in matlab using **[`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)**;

```
[m,~,n] = unique(data(:,1));
sumdata = [m, accumarray(n,data(:,2))];
```

for mean I would suggest **[`grpstats`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/grpstats.html?searchHighlight=grpstats)**:

```
avgdata = grpstats(data, DOY, {'mean'});
```

or as [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) suggested:

```
avgdata = accumarray(DOY, data, [], @mean);
```

---

You can also get what you want by using <kbd>Pivot Table</kbd> in excel and group data by `DOY` and get the mean value for them in the table. (No coding required).

Comment: I was thinking you could add `..., [], @mean` to the call to `accumarray`.

Comment: `avgdata = accumarray(DOY, data, [], @mean);` Yes. I agree, but like `grpstats` better personally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!